# Identify SMD component labelled W16 95

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to find out what element is the one that is on the PCB that is labeled as QD2. On the body it has mark W16 and 95, but I couldn't find anywhere on internet what this element is. This is from the dishwasher PCB. I believe it's not transistor.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

[image: SMD][image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you _believe it's not transistor_?  **Belief** shouldn't play a role. Have you traced out the surrounding schematic?

Comment: possibly a CMPZDA47V dual zener (if you don't believe it's a transistor)

Comment: Thank you both for reply. Well, there are other elements in the same housing with mark on top 6CW (and 94 beside) that have label Q on the board, while this one has QD, therefore I was assuming it's not transistor (or at least only a transistor).

Comment: In addition, PIN that is single on one side goes to a relay that turns on and off heat pump.

Comment: The other two pins goes to ground and IC - dma24mrelux

Comment: Still not enough info, but -assuming- that the QD1 is going to the relay solenoid as opposed to the contacts.  With that circuit configuration, a BJT/FET would make sense.  The QD could stand for an internal darlington BJT, for higher current gain.  Normally a FET would be used as this puts much less strain on the driver IC pin current-wise.  Of course parts can always be changed over time without updating the PCB silkscreen.  If that part has failed, I would check the resistance of the relay solenoid to make sure it hasn't shorted.

Comment: Hi isdi, thank you for your feedback. Relay should be fine as this was the first thing I replaced. Even i checked the old one and it still clicks. I added another photo of the board. There are in total 8 of these QD elements. I'll try more to find out if anything comes out on google with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an NPN pre-biased 100mA/50V transistor with 10K series base and 10K shunt emitter-base resistors.

Nexperia [PDTC114ET](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTC114E_SER.pdf)

[image]

P.S. The QD2 device appears to have suffered a traumatic death. Suggest checking the flyback diode as they sometimes fail short (especially the LL4148 variety), which of course will kill any replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much Spehro. This looks very promising. Do you know what "95" stands for on the transistor? I found some "W16" on internet, but they have differend second number. I wonder what role it plays.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: 95 is probably the date code or similar thing with little meaning.

Comment: Hi Spehro. I would like to thank you once again for your tips. I didn't had chance till today and was also waiting for the transistor to arrive, but now I managed to replace it and after that it burned out again. Then I checked the flyback diode which was showing zeros in both direction. Luckily I had something on stock so I replaced it with 1n4148 though I'm not sure what the old one was. Anyway the relay that turns on the water heater now heats the water.

Thanks again and happy new year!